# Pdfmake keep two rows together on page break when to page break on table

Tags: javascript, pdf, export, pdfmake, page-break

For the pdfmake, I have a table in which it uses two rows per record. Ex: [image]
and when the table breaks it breaks by each row. However, I want it to break after or before 2 rows in a table, which you keep the two rows together in one page.

Instead of :
[image]

I want the two rows to be in the same page. Is there a way to make sure this happens? I've tried to use the pageBreakBefore function, however I'm not that intuitive with it and there haven't been any good examples online.

```
var dd = {
        content: [
    
        'The following table has nothing more than a body array',
        {
            style: 'tableExample',
            table: {
               dontBreakRows:true,
              //  headerRows:1,
                body: [
                    [{text:'Col', colSpan:3, fillColor:'grey'}, {},{}],
                    [{text:'Column 1',fillColor:'blue'}, {text:'Column 2',fillColor:'blue'}, {text:'Column 3',fillColor:'blue'}],
                    ['One value goes here', 'Another one here', 'OK?'],
                    [{text:'Description:\n'+'sdfgdhfjsfgvbnfhjfhjfghjgfjgfjfhjfghjgffghjgfasfsjgkfldshgfkld',colSpan:3}],
                                        ['One value goes here', 'Another one here', 'OK?'],
                    [{text:'Description:\n'+'sdfgdhfjsfgvbnfhjfhjfghjgfjgfjfhjfghjgffghjgfasfsjgkfldshgfkld',colSpan:3}]
,
                    ['One value goes here', 'Another one here', 'OK?'],
                    [{text:'Description:\n'+'sdfgdhfjsfgvbnfhjfhjfghjgfjgfjfhjfghjgffghjgfasfsjgkfldshgfkld',colSpan:3}]
,                   ['One value goes here', 'Another one here', 'OK?'],
                    [{text:'Description:\n'+'sdfgdhfjsfgvbnfhjfhjfghjgfjgfjfhjfghjgffghjgfasfsjgkfldshgfkld',colSpan:3}]
,                   ['One value goes here', 'Another one here', 'OK?'],
                    [{text:'Description:\n'+'sdfgdhfjsfgvbnfhjfhjfghjgfjgfjfhjfghjgffghjgfasfsjgkfldshgfkld',colSpan:3}]
,                   ['One value goes here', 'Another one here', 'OK?'],
                    [{text:'Description:\n'+'sdfgdhfjsfgvbnfhjfhjfghjgfjgfjfhjfghjgffghjgfasfsjgkfldshgfkld',colSpan:3}]
,


                ],
            }
        },
    ]
    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can handle it like this:

```
pageBreakBefore: function(currentNode, followingNodesOnPage, nodesOnNextPage, previousNodesOnPage) {
  //Here you can change the criteria of pageBreak according to your requirement
  if (currentNode.id === 'myid' && (currentNode.pageNumbers.length != 1 || currentNode.pageNumbers[0] != currentNode.pages)) {
    return true;
  }
  //Here you can change the criteria of pageBreak according to your requirement
  else if (currentNode.id === 'mySecondid' && currentNode.pageNumbers.length != 1) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
},
```

Answer (score 0):

You could define these rows as separate tables, each in one row in root table. This way, rows won't be separated because they will be in one row in top-level table

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I have found that most of these fields as described by https://pdfmake.github.io/docs/0.1/document-definition-object/page/ like id: simply do not work at all - they are undefined in PdfMake-0.2.7 and in v0.3.0-beta.7. I cannot find anyone who reported this problem nor anyone who fixed it.

But I did find another way to get a forced page break: you can put the attribute: pageBreak: 'before' or pageBreak: 'after' or pageBreak: '' in elements that you manually create in a static PDFMake Document or manually pushing with body.push.

For the method to work when building using push to the array keep track of the lines per page and calculate the maximum number of lines that can fit on a page, excluding header and footer area and code it yourself.

**This is a sample code fragment:**

```
const maxRowsPerPage = 34; //I counted the maximum number of displayable rows on the page from an earlier version of this PDF file (includes header/data rows and blank rows). - they are all using the same font & size currently so this can work. 

var curLineNumberForCurPage = 1;

var myRows = $('#myTable tbody tr.myClass-tbody-tr');
myRows.each(function () {

var html = this.cells[4].innerHTML; //Hidden Table
html = html.replaceAll("\"", "'"); //Must change double quote to single quote in order for the $.parseHTML(html) to work correctly.
var myChildTable= $($.parseHTML(html));
var myChildTableRows = myChildTable.find("tr");
var cnt = myChildTableRows .length;
var totalRowsForColumn1 = cnt + 3 + 1;


var pageBreak = "";
if (curLineNumberForCurPage + totalRowsForColumn1 > maxRowsPerPage && totalRowsForEvent <= maxRowsPerPage) {
    //We must protect against the case where totalRowsForColumn1 > maxRowsPerPage - we dont want any extra blank pages!
    //if its bigger than what can fit on an empty page, just let it ride - i.e. dont force a page break.
    pageBreak = "before";
    curLineNumberForCurPage = 1;
}

//My header for each parent Table row:
body.push([{ text: "Column1", style: "styleColumn1", pageBreak: pageBreak }, 
            { text: "Column2", style: "styleColumn2", pageBreak: pageBreak },
            { text: "Column3", style: "styleColumn3", pageBreak: pageBreak },
            { text: "Column4", style: "styleColumn4", pageBreak: pageBreak }]);
curLineNumberForCurPage++;
```